# Error sending data to firebase using python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to send sensor data to firebase using python but i got some error. Here is my code

```
import serial
import time
import requests
import json
firebase_url = 'https://firebaseio.com'
ser = serial.Serial('COM8', 9600, timeout=100)

fixed_interval = 1

while 1:
    try:
        ser.flush()
        sensor = ser.readline()

        times = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        date = time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

        waktu = { 'date': date, 'time': times}

        par = sensor.decode("utf-8")
        print(par)
        data = { 'waktu': waktu, 'parameter': par}
        result = requests.post(firebase_url + '/node.json', data=json.dumps(data))
        print('Record inserted. Result Code = ' + str(result.status_code) + ',' + result.text)
    except IOError:
        print('Error')
```

I have changed my firebase rules to

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

But still error

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: nothing error on code, its error to send data to firebase. after it print variable "par" on terminal then code run "print ("error)"